# Java "||" String replace by "OR"

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I have a string like

> "age = 18 || name = 'Mistic' || civilstatus = 'married' || gender =
>   '0' "

and i need to replace "||" by "OR". I tryied following code.

```
System.out.println("age = 18 || name = 'Mistic' || civilstatus = 'married' || gender = '0'".replaceAll("||", "OR"));
```

but i got

> "ORaORgOReOR OR=OR OR1OR8OR OR|OR|OR ORnORaORmOReOR OR=OR
>   OR'ORMORiORsORtORiORcOR'OR OR|OR|OR
>   ORcORiORvORiORlORsORtORaORtORuORsOR OR=OR
>   OR'ORmORaORrORrORiOReORdOR'OR OR|OR|OR ORgOReORnORdOReORrOR OR=OR
>   OR'OR0OR'OR"

What i need is

> "age = 18 OR name = 'Mistic' OR civilstatus = 'married' OR gender =
>   '0' "

How can i achieve this.

> Edit
>   I have read the question and answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24303516/printing-a-replaced-line-in-a-new-text-file) and it is not simiar. Because that question is about replacing string and my question is about getting unfamiliar result to my code.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt This question is not a duplicate with my question.

Comment: Why is it not a duplicate? The  OP of that question had the same confusion as you had and the answer is the same. You should also look at the highest voted answer to your own question. The answer to the duplicate explains better why you may be confused between `replaceAll` and `replace`.

Comment: That is because `replaceAll` takes a regular expression, like `split`. Look at the linked question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`|` has a *special meaning* in regex. You need to escape it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "age = 18 || name = 'Mistic' || civilstatus = 'married' || gender = '0' ";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\|\\|", "OR"));
}
```

O/P :

```
age = 18 OR name = 'Mistic' OR civilstatus = 'married' OR gender = '0'
```

PS : Alternatively, you can use `Pattern.quote()` to escape special characters.

```
String  st = Pattern.quote("||");
System.out.println(s.replaceAll(st, "OR"));
```

Answer (score 10):

Why are you using `replaceAll` when you are not wanting to replace by regex?

Try just using normal `replace`

```
System.out.println("age = 18 || name = 'Mistic' || civilstatus = 'married' 
    || gender = '0'".replace("||", "OR"));
```

Output

> > age = 18 OR name = 'Mistic' OR civilstatus = 'married' OR gender = '0'

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the "||"s since they are meta characters in regular expressions.

Use:

```
System.out.println("age = 18 || name = 'Mistic' || civilstatus = 'married' || gender = '0'".replaceAll("\\|\\|", "OR"));
```

The reason why you are getting:

> "ORaORgOReOR OR=OR OR1OR8OR OR|OR|OR ORnORaORmOReOR OR=OR
>   OR'ORMORiORsORtORiORcOR'OR OR|OR|OR
>   ORcORiORvORiORlORsORtORaORtORuORsOR OR=OR
>   OR'ORmORaORrORrORiOReORdOR'OR OR|OR|OR ORgOReORnORdOReORrOR OR=OR
>   OR'OR0OR'OR"

Is because the regular expression "||" says "replace an empty string OR an empty string OR an empty string" with "OR". In other words, replace all empty strings with "OR".

Answer (score 2):

Use `Pattern.quote`

```
System.out.println("age = 18 || name = 'Mistic' || civilstatus = 'married' || gender = '0'".replaceAll(Pattern.quote("||"), "OR"));
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use replace instead of replaceAll, try using the following..

```
    System.out.println("age = 18 || name = 'Mistic' || civilstatus = 'married' || gender = '0' ".replace("||", "OR"));
```

Comment: why are you assigning to a string, then not even using it?

Comment: oh yes, thank you no need to take string, I corrected..

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the special characters in the input string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to replace all '||' with "OR"

```
String str = "age = 18 || name = 'Mistic' || civilstatus = 'married' || gender = '0' ";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\|\\|", "OR"));
```